# DCMotorTest from the Adafruit site – got fatal error exit status 1

Tags: adafruit, arduino-motor-shield

New to Arduino, I plugged in DCMotorTest from the Adafruit site and got this error message: a fatal error exit status 1

```
/* 
This is a test sketch for the Adafruit assembled Motor Shield for Arduino v2
It won't work with v1.x motor shields! Only for the v2's with built in PWM
control

For use with the Adafruit Motor Shield v2 
---->   http://www.adafruit.com/products/1438
*/

#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MotorShield.h>
#include "utility/Adafruit_MS_PWMServoDriver.h"

// Create the motor shield object with the default I2C address
Adafruit_MotorShield AFMS = Adafruit_MotorShield(); 
// Or, create it with a different I2C address (say for stacking)
// Adafruit_MotorShield AFMS = Adafruit_MotorShield(0x61); 

// Select which 'port' M1, M2, M3 or M4. In this case, M1
Adafruit_DCMotor *myMotor = AFMS.getMotor(1);
// You can also make another motor on port M2
//Adafruit_DCMotor *myOtherMotor = AFMS.getMotor(2);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);           // set up Serial library at 9600 bps
  Serial.println("Adafruit Motorshield v2 - DC Motor test!");

  AFMS.begin();  // create with the default frequency 1.6KHz
  //AFMS.begin(1000);  // OR with a different frequency, say 1KHz

  // Set the speed to start, from 0 (off) to 255 (max speed)
  myMotor->setSpeed(150);
  myMotor->run(FORWARD);
  // turn on motor
  myMotor->run(RELEASE);
}

void loop() {
  uint8_t i;

  Serial.print("tick");

  myMotor->run(FORWARD);
  for (i=0; i<255; i++) {
    myMotor->setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }
  for (i=255; i!=0; i--) {
    myMotor->setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }

  Serial.print("tock");

  myMotor->run(BACKWARD);
  for (i=0; i<255; i++) {
    myMotor->setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }
  for (i=255; i!=0; i--) {
    myMotor->setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
  }

  Serial.print("tech");
  myMotor->run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);
}
```

***My error message was:***

```
Arduino: 1.6.7 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

/Users/student/Downloads/Adafruit_Motor_Shield_V2_Library-master/examples/DCMotorTest/DCMotorTest.ino:11:34:
 fatal error: Adafruit_MotorShield.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Adafruit_MotorShield.h>
                                  ^
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
Error compiling.

  This report would have more information with
  "Show verbose output during compilation"
  enabled in File > Preferences.
```

Comment: 1. Did you install the `Adafruit_MotorShield.h` library? 2. If you did, did you do it without the IDE running, or restart the IDE afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error report it seems that you have just opened the example program from the downloaded folder. In order to add library files (which includes the header files, c++ source code, etc.) you have to move the *Adafruit_Motor_Shield_V2_Library-master* folder to the libraries folder.

> Documents > arduino > libraries

If no such folder exist, then create a new folder and name it *libraries*.

To check weather the libraries have been installed, open arduino IDE goto

> file > example and check weather the example programs are added (you will see "adafruit" in the list)

Now, restart the arduino IDE and things should get going.

**Note:**
Do not use "-" and do not include space while naming a folder, as the compiler may throw up error. Instead you are free to use "_","$". Name of a folder should always start with a letter.

For more detail visit https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-all-about-arduino-libraries-install-use/how-to-install-a-library